# Капча с генерацией строки JS

Tags: javascript, html

Впервые что-либо делаю на js, необходимо по заданию выполнить капчу с генерацией строки.
Не получается сравнить введенное значение с сгенерированным, после чего вывести соответствующее модальное окно.
Не совсем понимаю, как создать событие нажатия кнопки, предполагаю, что проблема в этом.
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

```js
let resInput = document.querySelector('#res-input');
let bttn = document.querySelector('#bttn');
let bttn2 = document.querySelector('#bttn2');

bttn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let res = '';
  let str = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    res += str[getRandom(0, str.length - 1)]; //генерация капчи

  }
  resInput.value = res;
});

function getRandom(min, max) { //рандомное значение
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max - min + 1) + min;
}


str.innerHTML = `${res} `; // События нажатия на кнопку
bttn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let nInput = document.querySelector("#nInput").value;

  if (nInput == res) {
    // То выводит "Вход разрешён"
    alert("Вход разрешён");
  } else {
    // Иначе выводит "Вход запрещен"
    alert("Вход запрещен");
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="res-input">
<button id="bttn">click me</button>
<input class="nInput" type="text">
<button id="bttn2">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте пройдём по коду сверху вниз:

1. Вы указали `<input class="nInput" type="text">` как поле ввода для проверяемого значения. Чуть позднее Вы пытаетесь считать значение данного поля через `document.querySelector("#nInput").value;`, однако этого не происходит. Дело в том, что значение селектора, начинающееся со знака `#`, обозначают id того или иного элемента, а у Вас был класс. Чтобы исправить данную проблему, Вы можете написать либо `id="nInput"` в строке с `input`, либо изменить селектор на `querySelector(".nInput"). В примере выше я использовал первый вариант.
2. Переменные `res` и `str` в Вашем коде не видны, так как они находятся в области видимости функции `addEventListener` (подробнее про области [тут](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/3.2.php) и [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/517338/)). Из этого следует, что они существуют только в данной функции, а для всего остального кода они не видны, а следовательно, и обратиться к ним нельзя. Чтобы они стали видны вновь, вынесите объявление + инициализацию из тела функции.

```html
<input type="text" id="res-input">
<button id="bttn">click me</button>
<input id="nInput" type="text">
<button id="bttn2">click me</button>

<script>
let resInput = document.querySelector('#res-input');
let bttn = document.querySelector('#bttn');
let bttn2 = document.querySelector('#bttn2');

let res = '';
let str = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';

bttn.addEventListener('click', function () {
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
res += str[getRandom(0, str.length - 1)]; //генерация капчи

}
resInput.value = res;
});

function getRandom(min, max) { //рандомное значение
return Math.floor(Math.random() * max - min + 1) + min;
}


str.innerHTML = `${res} `; // События нажатия на кнопку
bttn2.addEventListener("click", function () {
let nInput = document.querySelector("#nInput").value;

if (nInput == res) {
// То выводит "Вход разрешён"
alert("Вход разрешён");
} else {
// Иначе выводит "Вход запрещен"
alert("Вход запрещен");
}

});

</script>
```